# Парсинг JSON на Android

Tags: java, android, json, синтаксический-анализ, парсер

Всем добрый вечер.
Имеется `JSON` файл который необходимо распарсить. Структура `JSON` ниже:

```
{      

 "Italiano" : [
                {
"Хлеб" : [
                                {"title" : "Тосты",
        "image" : "664e5b1b1d8a165606df981e2ac3a94e.png",
        "price" : "39",
        "weight" : "90",
        "kkal" : "716",
        "description" : ""}
                ,                {"title" : "Лепешка Фокачи",
        "image" : "0761a99a6b6bd8f7d359436b81148e44.png",
        "price" : "39",
        "weight" : "110",
        "kkal" : "463",
        "description" : ""}
                ,                {"title" : "Хлебная корзинка",
        "image" : "20ae95142285d371239a3f2276a3a044.png",
        "price" : "20",
        "weight" : "100",
        "kkal" : "171",
        "description" : ""}
            ]
        }
        ,        {
"Итальянская пицца" : [
                                {"title" : "«МАМА ROOMA» 25 см.",
        "image" : "d7d4141657a3e200f0985dce2833c12b.png",
        "price" : "379",
        "weight" : "360",
        "kkal" : "",
        "description" : ""}
                ,                {"title" : "«МАМА ROOMA» 32 см.",
        "image" : "d7d4141657a3e200f0985dce2833c12b.png",
        "price" : "479",
        "weight" : "550",
        "kkal" : "",
        "description" : ""}
```

Файл полностью: http://zalil.ru/34710700

Необходимо при парсинге создать массив из категорий (Хлеб,Итальянская пицца и т.д.), а далее распарсить каждую категорию отдельно. Открыть файл могу, могу создать и `JSONObject`  и `JSONArray` и даже все это могу выполнить в фоновом потоке. Но проблема в том, что я уже два часа туплю, но ни как не могу написать алгоритм парсинга данного файла. Прошу помогите! Видимо я сам из этого стопора не выйду! 
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Создаете класс, который будет содержать нужные поля. Потом, имея JSONObject вызываете к примеру .optString("name", "def_value"); - в зависимости от интересующей переменной.

Comment: Можно примерно код, который бы получил хотя бы категории?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Подробнее:

Получили json - достали из него например `JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("Хлеб")`.

Далее заводим класс `Bread`

```
public class Bread {

public final String image;
public final int price;
public final int weight;
public final int kkal;
public final String description;

public Bread(String image, int price, int weight, int kkal, String description) {
    this.image = image;
    this.price = price;
    this.weight = weight;
    this.kkal = kkal;
    this.description = description;
}

public static Bread fromJson(final JSONObject object) {
    final String image = object.optString("object", "");
    final int price= object.optInt("price", 0);
    final int weight= object.optInt("weight", 0);
    final int kkal= object.optInt("kkal", 0);
    final String description= object.optString("description", "");
    return new Bread(image,price,weight,kkal,description);
}

public static ArrayList<Bread> fromJson(final JSONArray array) {
    final ArrayList<Bread> breads = new ArrayList<Bread>();

    for (int index = 0; index < array.length(); ++index) {
        try {
            final Bread bread = fromJson(array.getJSONObject(index));
            if (null != bread) breads.add(bread);
        } catch (final JSONException ignored) {
        }
    }
    return breads;
}
}
```

И вызываем `ArrayList<Bread> breads = Bread.fromJson(array);` в нужном месте.

Остальное по аналогии

Comment: Скажите а как просто получить отдельно названия категорий для Italiano. Не массивом а просто каждый отдельно? (Хлеб, Американская пицца и т.д.)?