# Как разобрать XML полученный из OpenStreetMap?

Tags: java, xml, openstreetmap

Обращаюсь к OpenSteetMap для того что бы узнать ширину и долготу определенного города.

```
public static void main(String [] args){

    URL myUrl = null;
    BufferedReader in;

        myUrl = new URL("http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=london&format=xml");
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myUrl.openStream()));
        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        System.out.println("URL not correct!");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Делаю это через вот такой запрос в URL:

```
http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=london&format=xml
```

И получаю обратно (пока только на консоль для проверки) xml с нужными данными.
Вот так он выглядит:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<searchresults timestamp='Fri, 11 Sep 15 12:32:46 +0000' attribution='Data ֲ©     OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright'    querystring='london' polygon='false'    exclude_place_ids='127589734,4226465,127669745,395836,127707941,127958688,127958683,63201612,433421,422728,353284' more_url='http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?format=xml&amp;exclude_place_ids=127589734,4226465,127669745,395836,127707941,127958688,127958683,63201612,433421,422728,353284&amp;q=london'>
<place place_id='127589734' osm_type='relation' osm_id='65606' place_rank='16' boundingbox="51.2867602,51.6918741,-0.510375,0.3340155" lat='51.5073219' lon='-0.1276474' display_name='London, Greater London, England, United Kingdom' class='place' type='city' importance='0.9654895765402' icon='     http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/images/mapicons/poi_place_city.p.20.png'/><place place_id='4226465' osm_type='node' osm_id='485248691' place_rank='16' boundingbox="42.828097,43.148097,-81.4060295,-81.0860295" lat='42.988097' lon='-81.2460295' display_name='London, Ontario, Canada' class='place' type='city' importance='0.6415723047601' icon='http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/images/mapicons/poi_place_city.p.20.png'/><place place_id='127669745' osm_type='relation' osm_id='130591' place_rank='16' boundingbox="37.079759,37.15226,-84.1262619,-84.0359569" lat='37.1289771' lon='-84.0832646' display_name='London, Laurel County, Kentucky, United States of America' class='place' type='city' importance='0.49529223844486' icon='http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/images/mapicons/poi_place_city.p.20.png'/><place place_id='395836' osm_type='node' osm_id='153408665' place_rank='19' boundingbox="43.0277775,43.0677775,-89.0328881,-88.9928881" lat='43.0477775' lon='-89.0128881' display_name='London, Dane County, Wisconsin, United States of America' class='place' type='hamlet' importance='0.447828369551' icon='http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/images/mapicons/poi_place_village.p.20.png'/><place place_id='127707941' osm_type='relation' osm_id='182481' place_rank='16' boundingbox="39.85928,39.921786,-83.4789229,-83.3899969" lat='39.8864493' lon='-83.448253' display_name='London, Madison County, Ohio, United States of America' class='place' type='city' importance='0.43543898169688' icon='http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/images/mapicons/poi_place_city.p.20.png'/><place place_id='127958688' osm_type='relation' osm_id='2730965' place_rank='19' boundingbox="36.4734452,36.4884367,-119.4497698,-119.4385394" lat='36.4760619' lon='-119.4431785' display_name='London, Tulare County, California, United States of America' class='place' type='village' importance='0.41045232539126' icon='http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/images/mapicons/poi_place_village.p.20.png'/><place place_id='63201612' osm_type='way' osm_id='33062722' place_rank='16' boundingbox="35.315577,35.33814,-93.2726929,-93.1873749" lat='35.328973' lon='-93.2529553' display_name='London, Pope County, Arkansas, United States of America' class='place' type='city' importance='0.4084484386218' icon='http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/images/mapicons/poi_place_city.p.20.png'/><place place_id='433421' osm_type='node' osm_id='154301303' place_rank='19' boundingbox="38.1743567,38.2143567,-81.3886944,-81.3486944" lat='38.1943567' lon='-81.3686944' display_name='London, Kanawha County, West Virginia, United States of America' class='place' type='hamlet' importance='0.40707848858916' icon='http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/images/mapicons/poi_place_village.p.20.png'/><place place_id='422728' osm_type='node' osm_id='154001519' place_rank='19' boundingbox="41.1236709,41.1636709,-80.1686716,-80.1286716" lat='41.1436709' lon='-80.1486716' display_name='London, Mercer County, penna, United States of America' class='place' type='hamlet' importance='0.375' icon='http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/images/mapicons/poi_place_village.p.20.png'/><place place_id='353284' osm_type='node' osm_id='151379108' place_rank='19' boundingbox="32.2109892,32.2509892,-94.9643839,-94.9243839" lat='32.2309892' lon='-94.9443839' display_name='London, Rusk County, Texas, United States of America' class='place' type='hamlet' importance='0.375' icon='http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/images/mapicons/poi_place_village.p.20.png'/></searchresults>
```

Нужные значения это 'lot' и 'lan' первые встречающиеся в этом файле.
Я читаю этот xml построчно через BufferedReader, каким образом можно извлечь эти данные для для их дальнейшего использования?

Comment: ИМХО лучше используйте json вместо xml, изменив format на format=json

Comment: Ну хорошо допустим я поменяю на json. Как достать эти поля?

Comment: в сети множество примеров парсинга json, вот пример http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/250288/176223

Answer (score 1):

> каким образом можно извлечь эти данные для для их дальнейшего
>   использования?

Используйте XPath ([пример 1](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/x-javaxpathapi/index.html), [пример 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java)). Это сразу решит очень многие проблемы связанные с получением данных из XML.